# Why does this code print out only the first letter?

Tags: python, string, return, return-value, uppercase

```
Word=input('please enter a word')
def cap(word):
      for char in word:
            if char in 'aeiou':
                  return letter.upper()

            else:
                  return letter

result=cap(word)
print result
```

Comment: Because you can only return from a given function invocation once.

Comment: Ohhh. Please how do I make it iterate?

Comment: Build a single result to return. Also I'd suggest upgrading to Python 3.

Comment: Collect the letters in a list or append to string and finally (after the loop) return that.

Comment: I use python 3. Here is the question: Build a function to  capitalize every vowel in a string

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Along with the main issue, you're iteration variable is `char` but you're returning `letter`. Also `Word != word`

Comment: To capitalize every vowel in an input

Comment: Ohhh. That was a mistake, I'd change that now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you can have functions that continuously return values — they're called generators. You just use `yield` instead of return. You can then use them as iterators, or call `list` on them to get the values:

```
word=input('please enter a word')
def cap(word):
      for letter in word:
            if letter in 'aeiou':
                  yield letter.upper()

            else:
                  yield letter

result=cap(word)
print(''.join(list(result)))
```

However, if your goal is to translate a set of characters to another set of characters, there is a python string method for that: [`translate`()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

```
word=input('please enter a word')
upper_vowels = word.translate(str.maketrans('aeiou', 'AEIOU'))

print(upper_vowels)
```

This should be more efficient that looping and joining as well being easier to read. Also, you can save the translate table separately if you want to apply it to many strings.

Answer (score 3):

You return immediately after examining the first character. Instead, you should go over all of them, and modify the ones you need.

```
def cap(word):
    result = ''
    for letter in word:
        if letter in 'aeiou':
            result += letter.upper()
        else:
            result += letter
    return result
```

Note, however, that this may be much easier to do with list comprehensions:

```
def cap(word):
    return ''.join(l.upper() if l in 'aeiou' else l for l in word)
```